# Random infinite binary sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, random, infinity, binary

What I mean by random infinite binary sequence is an infinite sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s with probability of occurrence in this sequence equal to $1/2$ (all digits being equally likely).

How is it defined and what are its properties? Are there many such (different) sequences or is it just one?

Can we say that the [Champernowne constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) in base two $C_2 = 0.11011100101110111…$ (actually the digits after the "$0.$") is such a sequence?

Comment: You might be interested about [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_diagonal_argument) ;)

Comment: Try Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sequence

Comment: It would appear that 01010101010101010... is random, by your definition. There are better definitions. There is a fine discussion in Volume 2, Seminumerical Algorithms, of Knuth's The Art Of Computer Programming.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different notions of "randomness", the most generally used one is the [Martin-Lof random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin-Lof_random). It has 3 equivalent definitions. Intuitively, a random sequence is hard to compress, hard to describe, and hard to predict the next digit, which is where the 3 definitions come from.

Champernowne constant is NOT a random sequence，it is a [computable real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_real_number), no computable real is random.